# If Statement With Multiple Lines

Tags: vba, if-statement, line-breaks

I have an `if` statement with multiple conditions. I cannot see them all in a single window view. Is there a way to separate them on different lines or do they have to be written all in one line?

Comment: I think I must be the only person who rathers it all on one line, even many pages wide, I just find it hard to follow broken in to seperate lines

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The VBA line-continuation character is an underscore `_`

```
if ( _
    (something) _
    or (somethingelse) _
)
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use the line continuation character `_`

These are all the same:

```
If Something Or  SomethingElse Or AnotherThing Then

If Something Or SomethingElse _
   Or AnotherThing Then

If Something Or _
   SomethingElse Or _
   AnotherThing Then
```

Answer (score 4):

Like the above, you can break up the long set of conditions in one "IF" statement by using an underscore.

If there are too many conditions and I find it challenging to read, I use BOOLEANS to represent the conditions.  It seems like there is more code, but I find it easier to read.

If I have a scenario where I need to do the following:

```
IF (X = something1) OR (X = something2) OR (X = something2) OR (X = something2) OR (X = something2) OR (X = something2) OR (X = something2) OR (X = something2) THEN
END IF
```

I could do this:

```
IF _
    (X = something1) _
    OR (X = something2) _
    OR (X = something3) _
    OR (X = something4) _
    OR (X = something5) _
    OR (X = something6) _
    OR (X = something7) _
    OR (X = something8) _
THEN
END IF
```

... or I could do this ...

```
blnCondition1 = (X = something1)
blnCondition2 = (X = something2)
blnCondition3 = (X = something3)
blnCondition4 = (X = something4)
blnCondition5 = (X = something5)
blnCondition6 = (X = something6)
blnCondition7 = (X = something7)
blnCondition8 = (X = something8)

IF blnCondition1 OR blnCondition2 OR blnCondition3 OR blnCondition4 OR blnCondition5 OR blnCondition6 OR blnCondition7 OR blnCondition8 THEN
END IF
```

Of course, the example BOOLEAN variables are defined, and instead of names like blnCondition1, I'll use meaningful names.

Again, it's just a preference I have.

Answer (score 3):

break them with an under score _ ?

[Microsoft Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa163834(v=office.10).aspx)

from above link

```
If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.ChartTitle = _
      ActiveSheet.Range("a2").Value Then
   MsgBox "They are equal."
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

im pretty sure you can use an underscore `_` to break up lines.

Comment: Tried it... but didn't work.
However one of the answers worked out.

Comment: from memory it can be a little picky as to where you are allowed to break up a line.

Comment: @Yokhen, then please close out your question. Its very busy already!