# I can't use the underscore (_) to break the if statement in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, line-breaks

```
If T_ANAME.Text = "" Or R_MALE.Checked = False Or R_FEMALE.Checked = False Or R_OTHERS.Checked = False _

Or (C_COUNTRY.Text = "-- Select Country --") _ Then

End If
```

This code shows syntax error.

I referred this page too
[If Statement With Multiple Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303821/if-statement-with-multiple-lines)

Comment: Perhaps you should remove the latest underscore, the one just before Then?

Comment: VBA (in the linked post) is not VB.NET.  In VB.NET you can break after any of the `Or` or `And` keywords without the underscore unless your VS is very very old (those should be `OrElse`)

Comment: Bad example to follow since you are using `VB.NET` and not `VBA` however remove the underscore before the `Then`. And backspace your `Or` line so it's right under the `If` line. Can't be a gap.

Comment: And consider to use OrElse instead of Or. Just test for true one of the conditions is enough See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170754/or-versus-orelse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the extra _ at the end of the logical statement.

```
If T_ANAME.Text = "" Or R_MALE.Checked = False Or R_FEMALE.Checked = False Or R_OTHERS.Checked = False _
Or (C_COUNTRY.Text = "-- Select Country --") Then
' do something 
End If
```